# Customer account url in different languages

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multidomain

I have two stores on my website English (test.com) and Spain (test.es). How do I specify the login url for customer accounts? On the English site it would be test.com/customer/account/login/ and on the Spanish site I want the login url to be test.es/clientes/cuenta/iniciarsesión/.
I have added a custom url rewrite with the following:

```
Type: Custom
Store: Spain
ID Path: Login
Request Path: clientes/cuenta/iniciarsesión/
Target Path: customer/account/login/
Redirect: No
```

But when I go to test.es/clientes/cuenta/iniciarsesión/ I see the page not found message (in Spanish). If I go to test.se/customer/account/login/ the login page will appear.

How can I get it to work so the customer login page (and other customer account pages) uses a Spanish url (that I would specify or generate automatically)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a discussion on how it can be achieved and the pro's and con's of doing it [Translate url keys when switching store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/66913/translate-url)