# Best practice for multilangual static content in Magento2

Tags: multistore, seo, page-content

I'm wondering how other developers handle multilingual stores in Magento2. I find it rather hard, because you'll want to optimize the URL keys for SEO in each language, but in doing so you lose the relation between pages.
That is why the [Magento documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/page-translate.html) tells us to use the same canonical URL key for all translations.

For instance, English `/about-us/` would translate to `/over-ons/` in Dutch. But when I open that page in any language and switch to another, I get a 404 page because it looks for the same URL key.

The same issue arises with menus. A lot of shops have static items/pages in their menus which each have their own URL key and label/name.

So what would you suggest is the best way to make this manageable?

My first thought would be to have a `.htaccess` file with rewrites, rewriting `about-us` to `over-ons` and back, but that would make it unmanageable with more languages and a lot of content.

Comment: You use page `Aboot Us` or `About us` ?

Comment: In the 'new' example it's like this; I have a Dutch store with a page "Over Ons", and an English store with a page "About Us".

Comment: Duplicate on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073043/different-url-keys-for-different-language-cms-pages/

Comment: closely related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/66913/translate-url-keys-when-switching-store

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a different CMS page for each language? Seems to me the Dutch page should have other content anyway. Just make a CMS page "About us" with url-key `about-us` on your English site, and another CMS page "Over ons" with url-key `over-ons` on your Dutch site.

Comment: Because when you switch from another language, you'd get a 404 page. Also, this creates the problem of having multiple instances of the same menu (a seperate menu per language). This is doable, but far from ideal, and I was hoping there would be a better solution

Comment: Which get's me thinking, a possible solution would be to add a custom attribute with (another) identifier which would be the same for all different languages of the same page, and use that identifier to get the current correct URL (and maybe redirect if coming from another).

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign the preferred localized URL key to each CMS page, e.g.:

   - EN: `about-us` to `cms/page/view/page_id/1` titled *About us*
   - NL: `over-ons` to `cms/page/view/page_id/2` titled *Over ons*
   - DE: `ueber-uns` to `cms/page/view/page_id/3` titled *Über uns*
2. Create [custom permanent redirects](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/url-rewrite-cms-page.html) (`Marketing -> URL Rewrites`) for the keys foreign to the Store View:

   - EN: `over-ons` to `about-us` and `ueber-uns` to `about-us`
   - NL: `about-us` to `over-ons` and `ueber-uns` to `over-ons`
   - DE: `over-ons` to `ueber-uns` and `about-us` to `ueber-uns`

These localized slugs are hard to maintain for a growing number of Store Views or static CMS pages, but may be worth the effort for UX and SEO.

PS: There are apparently some seemingly unmaintained extensions on GitHub for Magento 1 which try to simplify this maintenance task:

- https://github.com/klein0r/magento-language-routes
- https://github.com/tzyganu/CmsRewrites