# Magento 1.9 : How to change URL /customer/account/login to /kupac/nalog/prijava/

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

What is the easiest way to

1. change the `/customer/account/login/` URL to  `/kupac/nalog/prijava/` but to preserve the functionality too?
2. I will also need to change `/product/id/X` to `proizvod/X` where `X` can be arbitrary string or number.
3. Lastly, I need to change URL:
   http://localhost/darnik/catalogsearch/result/?q=lajsna
   to this URL:
   http://localhost/darnik/katalog/pretrazi/?q=lajsna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite this core URL using `config.xml` of your module.

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <designer_url>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/kupac/nalog/prijava/#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/customer/account/login/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </designer_url>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <custom_product>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/proizvod\/(.*)#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/product/id/$1]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </custom_product>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

Comment: Hi. This looks like it is working. Please see my original question, I edited it. I also need to change `/product/id/X` to `proizvod/X` where `X` can be arbitrary string or number. Do you also know how to do that?

Comment: please check the updated answer

Comment: thanks! One more thing I need, and that is to translate the URL with querystring to a different URL, but with the same querystring added. Like this:
Change this:
http://localhost/darnik/catalogsearch/result/?q=lajsna
to this:
http://localhost/darnik/katalog/pretrazi/?q=lajsna

Comment: To translate routes for multiple stores, you can use this extension: https://github.com/klein0r/magento-language-routes.

Configurations are pretty straight forward to translate a route using this extension as you see in this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/hebz01

Comment: I won't use that extension. I just used what you said in the answer and updated in the comment and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: happy to hear that it worked for you

Comment: Thanks again. You can also upvote all my comments and question, just as I did for yours. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using magento 1.9 then [this](https://github.com/klein0r/magento-language-routes) extension might help you.

You might want to look into this question too -
[Translate url keys when switching store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/66913/translate-url-keys-when-switching-store)